# ./configure command not working (linux mint 19.3)

Tags: linux-mint, terminal

I'm trying to figure out how to configure the source code for some program I installed and apparently you are supposed to use the `./configure` command, but whenever I use it, I end up getting this message:

> bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Any Advice?

Comment: That means that there is no `configure` script. What project are you trying to build?

Comment: @guillermochamorro: if OP pasted correct error they *do* run `./configure`

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? Where did you get the source from? Many projects use `autoconf` to create a `configure` script.

Comment: How did you determine that this particular application requires a configure script?

Comment: Presumably you did unpack the tarball into its own directory already? It normally unpacks `thisPackage.tar.gz` by creating a directory `thisPackage` right there, and all the code, README.txt and .configure end up one directory down. You run .configure, then usually `make all` and `make install`. The configure file is part of the package itself -- it is different for each package. It explores your system to find exactly what functionality it can use, and updates some files and scripts to match your exact environment.

Comment: ~10 different ways of "building from source" https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/install-tar-gz-file-like-spectrum-login-page-4175556531/#4

Comment: Check installation instructions. Not everybody uses the klunky autoconf (and friends) machinery from GNU. Even when they use it, it might be necessary to set it up. E.g. if you grab GNU bison from github, you have to run `./bootstrap` to create `configure` in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

`./configure` is the entry-point to launch configuration step for project using `autotools` as build system.

If the project you're working with use `autotools` but lacks `configure` script, then:

- Ensure you have a `configure.ac` file.
- Ensure you have `autotools` installed.
- Run `autoreconf -i`. This must build the configure script for your platform.

If the project you're working with lacks both `configure` and `configure.ac` files, then it is probably NOT using autotools, but `qmake`, `cmake`, `ninja`, etc... 
Search for a README file or something like that that should give you the correct way to build the sources.

Answer (score 0):

A command starting `./` must exist as an executable file in the **Current directory**.

It will be part of the package of source code that you downloaded. Unpack the source code, then `cd` to the root of this code. There should be a file named `configure` there. You can then run it (`./configure`).

## Warning

Before running random code that you downloaded, you should sandbox it. An easy way to do that is to add a new user to your system, and run the code as that user. This includes running `./configure` or `make`.